# Java desktop application with HTML5, JavaScript and OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx, openlayers-3

I'm developing a Java desktop application to display an interactive map using HTML5, JavaScript and OpenLayers. Requirements are,

1. The map has an editable vector layer which can be edited and then saved as a Json file. The saved layers can be reloaded on to the map as well.
2. Another application interacts with this application to get certain actions done such as, drawing a line between two points. This communication is done through sockets.

Because of this two-way communication requirement, an embedded browser was the easiest solution. So I tried JavaFX first, I loaded the map tiles which are stored in local file system  using file protocol and rendered onto HTML canvas using ol.source.XYZ. JavaScript functions were executed using executeScript method in WebEngine, and Java methods were executed from JavaScript using a [JSObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html). The problem was, HTML rendering was terrible in JavaFX.

The second option I tried was [the DJ project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/). It was perfect except, it won't work without ie11.

I'm wandering what to try next. If any of you have an idea please kindly point me out.

Comment: "HTML rendering was terrible in JavaFX" is not very specific. That makes it difficult to help.

Comment: @mipa By terrible I meant, it's very slow loading map tiles. Zooming , and panning takes noticeable response time. Bottom line is, it's not a very good user experience.